# Can a series be partially rearranged if it contains an absolute convergent series?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Consider an infinite series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}$, I assume it converges. Suppose we know that it contains an absolutely convergent series, i.e. $\sum_{i\in I}|a_{i}|$ converge for $I$ a subset of natural numbers. Now we do an rearrangement on the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}$, provided that the rearrangement does not change the order of non-absolute convergent part, will the series change its value or diverge?

By not changing the order of non absolute convergent part, I mean the following: Let the rearrangement mapping be $\sigma$, if  for all $j>i\in \mathbb{N}\backslash I$, then $\sigma(j)>\sigma (i)$.

Comment: If it converges, it always contains an absolutely convergent sub-series.

Comment: It will converge to the same limit as the original series.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Can you provide a proof?

Comment: I'm working on it. I'm 70 & I tire easily. Wait  a couple of days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes, every rearrangements converge to the same limit.

The sum can be written as follow:
$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i = \sum_{i=1}^\infty [b_i + \sum_{j=x_i}^{x_{i+1}-1} c_j] $$

Where the sequence $(c_i)$ is the absolute convergence part of $(a_i)$ and $(b_i)$ is the rest, both sequences are ordered exactly the same as $(a_i)$. $(x_i) \in \Bbb N$ is some monotonically increasing function with $x_1 = 1$. For the rearranged sum, there exists monotonically increasing sequences $(y_i), (m_k), (n_k)$ such that for all $k \in \Bbb N$:

$$\sum_{i=1}^k a_{\sigma(i)} = \sum_{i=1}^{n_k} [b_i + \sum_{j=y_i}^ {y_{i+1}-1} c_{\sigma(j)}] +  \sum_{i=y_{n_k+1}}^{m_k} c_{\sigma(j)} $$

Now we take the limit:
$$
\lim_{k \to \infty} \left|\sum_{i=1}^k a_{\sigma(i)} - \sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i\right|\\
= \lim_{k \to \infty} \left|\sum_{i=1}^{n_k} [b_i + \sum_{j=y_i}^{y_{i+1}-1} c_{\sigma(j)}] +  \sum_{i=y_{n_k+1}}^{m_k} c_{\sigma(j)}  - \sum_{i=1}^{n_k} [b_i + \sum_{j=x_i}^{x_{i+1}-1} c_j] \right| \\
 =\lim_{k \to \infty} \left|\sum_{i=1}^{n_k}\sum_{j=y_i}^{y_{i+1}-1} c_{\sigma(j)} -\sum_{i=1}^{n_k}\sum_{j=x_i}^{x_{i+1}-1} c_j+ \sum_{i=y_{n_k+1}}^{m_k} c_{\sigma(j)}\right|\\
 =\left|\sum_{i=1}^\infty c_{\sigma(i)} - \sum_{i=1}^\infty c_i + 0\right| = 0
$$

The last two equalities come from the fact that convergence series vanish at later terms and rearrangements of absolute convergence series are equal.